# Not able to see UWP 10 Phone Emulator in Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am unable to see windows phone 10 emulator while working on xamarin forms application.

I can open android, ios and windows desktop emulators but unable to see windows 10 phone emulator.

When I tried creating UWP I can see windows phone 10 emulators but not in Xamarin Forms.

[image]

Comment: what is the min version of UWP are you supporting?  I suspect that version of uwp does not support mobile

Comment: its 16299 I guess it doesn't support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [explained this in a blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2018/02/14/why-cant-i-deploy-my-uwp-app-with-net-standard-2-0-to-a-mobile-device-or-emulator/). This happens when you set the minimum and Target Version to at least Build 16299.

The Windows 10 Mobile platform hangs at feature2 branch, which is only creators updates level + a few fixes and but doesn't contain the features of the full Fall Creators Update Build 16299.

If you want to target Windows 10 Mobile, set the Target to Build 15063, but here you loose the possibility of using .net standard 2.0.

Comment: my build is 16299 and using .net standard 2.0 is there any other way I can run it..

Comment: there is no real way. Microsoft decided to stop building Mobile and PC/Tablets builds from same code branch and stop supporting Win10m in 2019.

Comment: do you mean microsoft stopping win 10 from xamarin forms ?

Comment: only mobile is dead now. The normal Desktop Windows 10 builds support .net standard 2.0 and run xamarin.forms apps.

Comment: any changes of they releasing to support .net standard 2.0 for win 10 mobile apps in xamarin forms

Comment: Microsoft needs to build the mobile version from same source code as the PC, but they don't do this any longer. The chief of Microsoft Satya Nadella doesn't like Win10 mobile, only his Azure cloud thing, so his killed Windows 10 Mobile.